# Openning workbook with FilePicker in VBA throws compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I define workbook as variable with FilePicker. At the top I defined my variable as public and string. I tried  to declare it as workbook but it doesnt work. Having it defined as string when I try to get into this workbook in another module I get the 
following compile error:

> Invalid qualifier.

Any suggestions what is wrong?

```
Public wipreport As String

sub wip()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select WIP Report"
        .ButtonName = "OK"
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        'Store in fullpath variable
        wipreport = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With

end sub
```

Line of code in another module, where I get this compile error:

```
wipreport.Worksheets("1. WIP report").Select
```

Thank You for help.

---

Answer (score 2):

Compile error is the best error you may have - the compiler tells explicitly it does not work. In this case, `wipreport.Worksheets("1. WIP report").Select` could not work, becase `wipreport` is of type `String` and it does not have `Worksheets` property.

Probably try something like this, it will work if `wipreport` is the name of the opened Excel file:

```
Workbooks(wipreport).Worksheets("1. WIP report").Select
```

If `wipreport` is a path of the file, then openning it is a better option:

```
Workbooks.Open wipreport
```

or even, setting a variable to it:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wipreport)
```

*And while on the subject, there is a reason that this question has the highest number of votes in #VBA in StackOverflow - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).*

Answer (score 2):

`FileDialog` returns the file name as `String` object, but you are trying to use it as `Workbook`.
If the user has selected the file, then you first need to open it and then try to select the sheet:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wipreport) 'open the file
wb.Worksheets("1. WIP report").Select ' your code
```